# how can I schedule an api call on every quarter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, logic

I want to send some user specific data to an API on every quarter after a user logs in. like every 9:15 then 9:30 then 9:45 and so on..
I can use setInterval for every 15 min but I want it to be exactly at the quarter.

**For Example - A user logs in at 9:25, so instead of hitting the API after 15 min(9:40) from then I want it to hit at 9:30 and then 9:45 and so on..**

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply check every minute if minutes % 15 == 0 and then hit your API

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to calculate time to next 15, 30, 45, 60 minute clock,
2. Use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) to set a timer to the calculated time,
3. Start a new interval using [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval).

```js
function onEveryQuarter(callbackFn) {
  // function that starts an interval that calls `callbackFn()` every 15 minutes
  const startQuarterInterval = () => setInterval(callbackFn, 60*1000*15); // in milliseconds
  // get minutes to next :15, :30, :45, :60 time
  const now = new Date();
  const nextQuarterTime = Math.abs(now.getMinutes() % 15 - 15) * 1000; // *1000 to convert to milliseconds
  // start timer
  const quarterTimer = setTimeout(startQuarterInterval, nextQuarterTime);
}
```

And then,

```js
// desired function
const myFunc = () => console.log("hello world");
// to execute `onEveryQuarter` as soon as user visits your site.
window.onload = (e) => onEveryQuarter(myFunc);
```

at top of your `main.js` file.

Comment: Looks great.. I'll try this!

Comment: @MohammadUbaid If it worked for you, please don't forget to mark this answer as "accepted'. :D